# XData size error for 3D Plotting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graphing

```
G = 

  graph with properties:

    Edges: [4782×2 table]
    Nodes: [692×0 table]

>> plot(G, 'XData', x1, 'YData', y1, 'ZData', z1)
Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.GraphPlot
Expected XData to be an array with number of elements equal to 692.
```

This is the output from creating a graph from an adjacency matrix, and then trying to stick the nodes to specific coordinates (x1,y1,z1), but it gives me the error about XData being the wrong size. I followed the tutorial from here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.html

I could reproduce the error with a smaller set:

```
a = [1 2 3]
b = [4 5 6]
c = [7 8 9]
d = [10 11 12]
e = [13 14 15]
f = [16 17 18]

G = graph(a,b,c)
plot(G, 'XData', d, 'YData', e, 'ZData', f)
```

Gives the same error except that the "number of elements equal to 6"

Comment: @CrisLuengo x1, y1, z1 are all doubles of size 692x1, and if G =graph(n1,n2,w), each of these are the same size as well. Not sure how to load an example that large without taking several pages.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you. I updated the original post, and got the same error. I also went in and checked, but x1, y1, z1 etc. are all size 4782x1, not 692x1, but it loads in 692 nodes. I believe that the way x1 and n1 are formed are causing the error, where (n1,n2) represents an edge, but (x1,y1,z1) represents a coordinate, but not all n1 are unique across all edges.

Comment: Thanks, this is excellent!

Answer (score 1):

Looking through [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html), it appears that you are using the `G = graph(s,t,weights)` form of the constructor for `graph`. In this form, `s` and `t` are node pairs. Each element pair `[s(i),t(i)]` indicates an edge between the nodes with ID `s(i)` and `t(i)`. The 3rd array gives the weight for each edge. Your graph therefore has 3 edges, and 6 nodes:

```
a = [1 2 3];
b = [4 5 6];
c = [7 8 9];
G = graph(a,b,c)
```

You have nodes numbers 1 through 6, with an edge between nodes 1 and 4, one between 2 and 5, and one between 3 and 6.

Therefore, you would need also 6 coordinates for these 6 nodes in the `plot` function.

Comment: Thank you. Just one question: when entering in the coordinates in plot(G, 'XData', x1...) What is the proper ordering for x1? If a = [3 2 1] and x1 = [1 2 3], what is the coordinate of node 3? is it 1 or 3?

Comment: @Ammastaro: Node 3 is at `x1(3) == 3`.